# EBS volume unmounted after EC2 instance type change

Tags: amazon-ec2, mount, amazon-ebs

I have an EC2 instance running mongo, with data stored on a separate EBS device.
I decided to change EC2 instance type, and when I restarted I did not see the disk anymore, so I had to mount again. Don't know if this is due to instance downgrade, or if my mount simple does not survive the instance restart. 
I mounted the disk with this command:

```
mount /dev/xvdf /data -o noatime -o noadirtime
```

Comment: You have to add it in `/etc/fstab` in order to be automatically mounted after the restart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to preserve a mount point after a server reboot, you have to add it in `/etc/fstab` [fstab](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab)

So you have to add the following line in `/etc/fstab`

`/dev/xvdf /data ext4     errors=remount-ro   0   2`

Comment: is there any command that, given a mount, ouput back the corresponding fstab entry? I want to ensure same parameters I used to mount command lien and I don't find an easy way to match

Comment: You can check the mount options with the command `mount | grep "/dev/xvdf" `